# How to add index attribute and value to selected elements dynamically by traversing all elements inside container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to traverse all the elements inside the container and find  anchor element which has class test-image-class and then add index attribute and value dynamically .

```
var containerHTML = test &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class ="test-image-class" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    these two images are not matching &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

tried the following but its not working

```
containerHTML.find('a.test-image-class').each(function(index){
  $(this).attr("index",index);
}                                             
console.log(containerHTML);
``
```

Comment: please put your HTML code as well here in HTML format.

Comment: FYI, you don’t need to _switch accounts_, just because you were told that you should show your efforts … https://stackoverflow.com/q/63111392/1427878

Comment: I had reached my question limit CBroe and its not my own account to switch

Comment: sure  Asutosh, it is random generated html in program mostly not formatted.

Answer (score 0):

With Formatted HTML:

```
containerHTML.querySelectorAll('a.test-image-class').forEach(function(elem, index){
    
      $(elem).attr("index",index);
    });
```

You may visit this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/pjgohn5x/

Without Formatted HTML:

```
var containerHTMLStr = 'test &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class ="test-image-class" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; & nbsp; < a class = "test-image-class" href = "" > < span > testimage < /span></a > & nbsp; & nbsp;these two images are not matching & nbsp; & nbsp; < a class = "test-image-class "href = "" > < span > testimage < /span></a > & nbsp; & nbsp ';
var el = $('<div></div>');
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(containerHTMLStr, "text/html");
doc.querySelectorAll('a.test-image-class').forEach(function(elem, index) {
  $(elem).attr("index", index);
});
console.log(doc.querySelector('body').innerHTML);
```

Please follow the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/a017bmkg/3/

Comment: this works for formatted html. but it is not working in my case of html

Comment: @GobikaK I see, I have edited the answer to handle non formatted case.